# Use PDO request in Magento 1.9 in the event "customer_register_success"

Tags: php, mysql, magento, core-data, pdo

I'm a french student (sorry for my bad English) and I have a problem with one thing in Magento. I would like to insert a customer, when he created his account, in a custom table named 'membre' in my database (of Magento).

So I created an Observer and the methods for, and when I test, I have an error HTTP 500 and in the logs file, I have few pieces of information.

But when I refresh the page the customer is registered but in my database I have nothing....

In my local module I have these files :

1. /www/app/code/local/Magentix/Gestion/etc/config.xml
   [config.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOIvJ.png)
2. /www/app/code/local/Magentix/Gestion/Model/Observer.php
   [Observer.php File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmH27.png)

   I'm lost and I don't understand what it is bad or not..

If you want more information, said it and I will try my best for realized that

Thanks.